# jQuery onclick event for <a> tag to change 'active' class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, navigationbar

I've seen a few posts about this but none have worked for me. Also, I think my problem has to do with the way I'm adding an html 'template' with jQuery. I think this might have to do with the scope but I'm not sure. I'm still a rookie in Web Design.

I'm using the '.active' class from bootstrap and I want to switch that class between the navigation buttons.
First I tried to do it following the instructions on these videos and finally from a few different SO posts.

***jQuery Tutorial: Add Active Class to Navigation Menu Item Based on URL***

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9lCqK_VrEE

***Nav Menu Active Click Item with jQuery***

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaWvfxUdz_k

This is the code I currently have.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/header.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/header.js"></script>

      <title>MNRentals | Dashboard</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="header"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**reservations.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/header.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/header.js"></script>
        <title> MNRentals | Reservations</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**header.html**

```
<!-- HEADER -->
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="logo">
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>MN</b>Rentals</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="float-right">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills card-header-pills">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="reservations.html">Reservations</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pagos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Propiedades</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<header>
```

**header.js**

```
(function ($) {
    $(document);
}(jQuery));

$(function () {
    $('#header').load('/pages/header.html');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav a').click(function () {
        $('.nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to toggle active class of `<a>` tag right? but you target `<li>` and not `<a>`

```
$('.nav li').click(function () {
    $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

change to

```
$('.nav li').click(function () {
    $('.nav li a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find("a").addClass('active');
});
```

UPDATED:

because you are loading `header.html` using jQuery it is possible that `.ready()` was executed before `header.html` actually loaded and and made the click event creation useless as is does not detect the element yet. To add the event after the element loads change:

```
$(function () {
    $('#header').load('/pages/header.html');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav a').click(function () {
        $('.nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

TO

```
$(function () {
  // modified
  $('#header').load('/pages/header.html', function () {
    $('.nav a').click(function () {
        $('.nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

[jQuery .load() complete callback reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized. I changed between <li> and <a> but nothing works. **I messed up while writing the post**. I will try to change it to what you suggest though. Thank you!

Comment: @user3329483 do not forget to upvote or accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: I just realized what was happening. With your code it works _only_ if the <a> doesn't link to another page. The new page ("reservations.html") loads the header _again_ with the <a> tag with .active class in the <a href="dashboard.html">
How do you think I should go about doing this? I'm not too good with jQuery and don't know how these things are usually made.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! First the problem was that I wasn't making sure the header.html file loaded before interacting with it. This was solved with @masterpreenz 's help. With that I realized that his code only worked if there wasn't any links in the  tag, so I was loading the new page with the first element of the navigation menu '.active' like in the old page.

What I did was implement the code from the first youtube video I posted inside the code @masterpreenz provided and now the current url is used to select the  to be highlighted.

***jQuery Tutorial: Add Active Class to Navigation Menu Item Based on URL***

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9lCqK_VrEE

The final jQuery code looks like this (I removed the '.active' class from the  tags in the "header.html" file:

```
$(function () {
    $('#header').load('/pages/header.html', function () {
        var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

        var target = $('.nav a[href ="' + path + '"]');

        target.addClass('active');

    });
});
```